# HTTP Status response returning 200 when I have set it to 201

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using AJAX for a login form, upon a user supplying the correct credentials it should redirect to a landing page.

This is the AJAX layout (login and register hit different functions in accounts.js):

```
login.html                        login.php
               -> accounts.js ->
register.html                     register.php
```

In both login.php and register.php there is code that checks the success like so:

```
if($success == 1)
{
     echo '$success';
     $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
         header(201);
     exit();
}
```

Register returns 201 if it successful, however login always returns 200 (but does echo the successful message)

The JS code:

```
xHRObject.open("GET", "login.php?id=" + Number(new Date) + options, true);
xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
   {
    alert(xHRObject.status);        
   }
   else if(xHRObject.status == 201)
   {
        window.location.href = 'landing.html';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

header takes a string as its parameter (not integer).

```
header("HTTP/1.0 201 Created")
```

or use [http_response_code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

```
http_response_code(201)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to output headers before any content.

Try moving `header(201);` to before the `echo` call and make sure you don't have anything else outputting even earlier.